# How to make Categories button functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I got my current website displaying hard coded data from my data.js file. I implemented firebase as my database and I want to have my categories button work with the firbase database. FYI, I'm fairly new to developing websites and apps. I'm going to attach my app.js and categories.js file.

Here is my code so far.

```
const allCategories = ["all", ...new Set(items.map((item) => item.category))];

const MenuApp = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(items);
  const [activeCategory, setActiveCategory] = useState("");
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories);

  const filterItems = (category) => {
    setActiveCategory(category);
    if (category === "all") {
      setMenuItems(items);
      return;
    }
    const newItems = items.filter((item) => item.category === category);
    setMenuItems(newItems);
  };
  
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="menu section">
        <div className="title">
          <img src={logo} className="logo" />
          <h2>Menu List</h2>
          <div className="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <Categories
          categories={categories}
          activeCategory={activeCategory}
          filterItems={filterItems}
        />
        <Menu items={menuItems} />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Categories = ({ categories, filterItems, activeCategory }) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn-container">
      {categories.map((category, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className={`${
              activeCategory === category ? "filter-btn active" : "filter-btn"
            }`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => filterItems(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

I attched screenshots of how my menu page looks like.
[image: Website]
[image: Updated DB]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show... anyway in ``allCategories`` you are spreading an object and mapping it? That will course some undesired side effects. Best you have an array of all your categories. Because currently you have a function inside an array and that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

here is how I would do it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About';
import Fire from './firebase/firebase-test'
import FireMenu from './firebase/firebase-menu'
import Menu from './Menu';
import items from "./data";
import Categories from "./Categories";
import { Full_Menu } from "./firebase/firebaseConfig";
import logo from "./img/logo.jpg"; // this could be a placeholder until we get their official logo

function App () {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/menu" element={<MenuApp />} />
        <Route path= "/fire" element={<Fire />}/>
        <Route path="/firemenu" element={<FireMenu />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
  
  );
}

const allCategories = ["all", ...new Set(items.map((item) => item.category))];

const MenuApp = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(items)
  const [activeCategory, setActiveCategory] = useState("all");

const filterItems = items?.filter(item => {
        switch (activeCategory) {
            case 'all':
                return true
            case 'all day specials':
            case 'appetizers':
            case 'add ins':
                return item.category === activeCategory
            default:
                return true
        }
    })
  
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="menu section">
        <div className="title">
          <h2>Menu List</h2>
          <div className="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <Categories
          setActiveCategory={setActiveCategory}
          activeCategory={activeCategory}
        />
        <Menu items={filterItems} />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

const allCategories = ['all','all day specials','appetizers','seafood platter', 'add ins', 'beef', 'chicken', 'chow mein', 'combinations', 'deep fried goodiness', 'dessert', 'fried rice',
'pork', 'seafood platter', 'sides', 'vegetable', 'whats cooking', 'wing']

const Categories = ({ activeCategory, setActiveCategory, }) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn-container">
      {allCategories.map((category, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className={`${
              activeCategory === category ? "filter-btn active" : "filter-btn"
            }`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => setActiveCategory(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

Comment: Hey @jonson.ncube I have a few questions. Although your code did work, I'm not too sure what I need to do in order to set categories in my database. I can add a screen shot of what my website looks like and how my database looks like.

Comment: @saulcinho can you first check ✅ what I recommended correct since it worked and mark it as useful.

Comment: @saulcinho You database should have a better structure... I will send you something in a moment.

Comment: Hey @jonson.ncube, can you help me still?

Comment: @saulcinho, your db needs to be like this ```>All_day_special {col}> firebase{id} > name: •••, price:•••, category:•••, spicy: true {doc}```

Comment: Hey @jonson.ncube, I set up my database like how you mentioned. The only thing I need help in is how to declare my firebase items onto my MenuApp(). You stated in line 2 that you're assuming "items" is from my database, but it's not. It's actually from my data.js file. I'm sure this is a simple fix. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Also, I updated my code based on what you suggested I should do @jonson.ncube

Comment: @saulcinho your categories in the database must not have spacing... use camel-case .e.g: ``chowMein``. This will prevent a lot of issues

Comment: Hey @jonson.ncube, My "items" is still taking data from my data.js file. Can you show me how to take the information I need from my firebase database?

Comment: Create another ticket and send me that link with the issue and I will send the answer

Comment: I made it, Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31623013 @jonson.ncube THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Have you seen it? @jonson.ncube

Comment: @saulcinho I am checking it now